# Does await pass control to the caller? Or does await suspend the thread? Why does the top level call need an await?

Tags: c#, async-await

1 thread is running the program.

It prints Main Method Started....

Then prints Some Method Started....

Then I was expecting that await `Task.Delay` will release the thread into the pool until the Task delay completes. But that seems to happen only if the call to SomeMethod would have been like this: `await SomeMethod();`

In the current example it prints Main Method End.... Does await pass control to the caller? Or does await suspend the thread?

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace AsynchronousProgramming
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Main Method Started......");
        SomeMethod();

        Console.WriteLine("Main Method End");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    public async static void SomeMethod()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Some Method Started......");

        //Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
        Console.WriteLine("\n");
        Console.WriteLine("Some Method End");
    }
 }
}
```

Comment: Are you familiar with JavaScript 's`Promise` , at all? or C++'s `future`? .NET's `Task<T>` works the same way - however using an `async void` method breaks everything because its caller has no way to wait or be notified - or be continued - when the result in the `Task<T>` resolves itself. In short: _don't use `async void`_ and you'll be fine.

Comment: @Dai - I think if it were Javascript then output would have been Main Method Started.... main method end... and then it would print some method started?

Comment: @Dai - are you saying that if I replace void with Task then the output will change?

Comment: If "await" suspended the thread, then there would be no need for "await". Suspending the thread is normal synchronous behavior during a Sleep.